# CakePHP 3, display current date

Tags: php, date, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I´ve read the documentation of CakePHP 3: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#dates

In my AppController.php I´ve added

```
use Cake\I18n\Date;
$date = new Date('2015-06-15');
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Germany/Berlin'));
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Class 'Cake\I18n\Date' not found.
```

Whats wrong with this?

I merely want to display the current date in my view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of cake are you using? print configure::version(); in one of your controllers

Comment: I´ve added `configure::version();` into my AppController. Error: `Class 'App\Controller\Configure' not found`.

Comment: Add use Cake\Core\Configure; to your controller, then try version again

Comment: In my composer.lock I´ve found `"name" : "cakephp/cakphp", "version" : "3.1.10"`. How do I update to 3.2? When I run `composer update` I get the message `nothing to install or update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you reference is new to CakePHP 3.2 - Your version is currently 3.1.x.

Navigate to your site directory and run the command `composer update`

Comment: I´ve done that. Unfortunately `composer update` says `nothing to install or update` again. And I´m sure, I´m in the right directory. (...\Xampp\htdocs\cake3)

Comment: I figured out, 3.2 requires PHP 5.5, but my current version of PHP is 5.4, I think.

Comment: Correction: PHP version: 5.5.6

Comment: @Leyla CakePHP 3.2.x requires PHP >= 5.5.9 so you will need to upgrade PHP in order to update to the latest Cake release.

Comment: @Leyla And you probably need to update the version constraint in your `composer.json` file (it's probably something like `3.1.*`, which will never ask for `3.2`, if it would, you'd get a different error about an unmet requirement (PHP version).

Comment: Thank you guys. I´ve updatet PHP and composer and now my PHP version is 5.6.15 and CakePHP version 3.2.2. You´re the really best. <3